# Downloading JAD file on BlackBerry simulator 9550

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, jad

I have a [JAD File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28file_format%29) which I want to run on my simulator. So I do these things to download that JAD file on my simulator ...

**I have changed the SD card and browse that project where the JAD file is kept**.

Now when I browse that SD card I find there is a JAD file. When I click on it I got one download button and one cancel button. On clicking the download button it gives me information like "downloading failed".

When I click on the details button it says **"invalid cod file not found"**. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .jad file does not contain any of your actual code.  It is actually a text file, you can open it in a text editor and read it.  The .jad file just contains pointers to your .code file(s).  So, you need to make sure that your .cod file(s) are available in the same folder as the .jad file.

Comment: And i dont have any cod file in there ..... it has some `.alx, .csl, .jdp` and some more file but not `.cod` file

Comment: you will need every one of those .cod files referenced in the .jad file in order to install the app.  What is the path where you have found those .alx, etc. files?  In my project, I have `deliverables\Standard\5.0.0` and in that folder a single .cod file.  If you rename that .cod file to .zip and then unzip, you will find your numerous .cod files.

Answer (score 1):

Build your app, and generate a .cod file. Then rename the .cod files to .zip file and then extract. Then you will get a set of .cod files. You need to have all of them and they should be signed.

You cannot download the .cod files to an SD card and install like Java ME. You need to either desktop software or your JDE or you need to deploy all of your .cod files along with your [JAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28file_format%29) file in some server. Then access the JAD file link from a browser. Here we go .. it's done.

Comment: This statement is not correct: "You cannot download the .cod files to an SD card and install".  You can, just add the jad and cod files (unzipped) to the SD Card, and use File Explorer to browser to them.  Double click on the jad, and it will install like you found it in the Browser.